# Get radio value from <form>

Tags: javascript, html

This is a simple web page for calculating ideal weight. My problem is that when I enter details and I select radio button for male or female the first if condition only works and the else if condition does not work. Selecting either is giving me the first condition answer.

What is the error? I have no problem getting height value from the form but gender's value is giving this error.

[When selected male it is giving the first condition only which is Female](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8iFK.png)

```js
function calculateWeight() {
  var men = 22 * Math.pow(document.getElementById('height').value, 2);
  var women = 22 * Math.pow(document.getElementById('height').value - 0.1, 2);

  if (document.getElementById('genderFemale').value == "female") {
    alert("The Ideal weight for you(women) is : " + women);
  } else if (document.getElementById('genderMale').value == "male") {
    alert("The Ideal weight for you (men) is : " + men);
  }

}
```

```html
<header class="header-content">
  <div class="logo">
    <h2>
      <a href="index.html"></a>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Calculator</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ideal Weight Table</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="row">
  <aside>
    <nav class="side-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Calculator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ideal Weight Table</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <section class="content-body">
    <div class="row">
      <form>
        <div style="margin: 0 100px 20px 100px; text-align:  center; border-color: #33F9FF ">
          <h2> Input Following Requirements :</h2>
          Age: <input style="margin-left: 43px; padding: 0;" type="number" name="Age">
          <br><br> Height:
          <input style="margin-left: 30px; padding: 0; width: 102px" list="units" type="number" step="any" name="Height" id="height">
          <select name="Unit" id="units">
         <option selected="selected">Unit ...</option>
         <option value="">inch</option>
         <option value="">ft</option>
         <option value="">cm</option>
         <option value="">metre</option>
        </select>

          <br><br> Gender:
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderMale" value="male" checked style="margin-left: 20px; padding: 0;"> Male
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderFemale" value="female"> Female
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
          <br>
          <br>

          <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateWeight()">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result use **document.getElementById('genderFemale').checked** and 
**document.getElementById('genderMale').checked** because value of those ids is always female and male respectively always

**JS:**

```
function calculateWeight()
{

var men = 22*Math.pow(document.getElementById('height').value,2);
var women = 22*Math.pow(document.getElementById('height').value - 0.1,2);

    if (document.getElementById('genderFemale').checked) 
    {
        console.log(document.getElementById('genderFemale').value)
      alert("The Ideal weight for you(women) is : " +women);
    } 
      else if (document.getElementById('genderMale').checked)
    { 
      console.log(document.getElementById('genderMale').value)
      alert("The Ideal weight for you (men) is : " +men);
    }
    }
```

**HTML:**: For every radio button add onchange function to call calculateWeight() function

```
Height:<input style="margin-left: 30px; padding: 0; width: 102px" list="units" type="number" step="any"  name="Height" id="height">

Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderMale" value="male" checked style="margin-left: 20px; padding: 0;" onchange="calculateWeight()"> Male

<input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderFemale" value="female" onchange="calculateWeight()"> Female

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" onchange="calculateWeight()"> Other
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GxgZmO?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks alot. I just wasted my time and in just 2 minute I got the answer from you.

Comment: Thanks @touqeer, glad my answer helped you ,  you can mark as answered , if it helped to solve your problem :) .. updated codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gebLKe?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your getting a static value from the radio box. If you look at the information you are grabbing in your if statements , you will see that the value is always the same.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderFemale" value="female">
```

The value of "female" is always "female" regardless of which box you check.

To grab which radio button is checked you would have to 'check' if the button itself is checked, via the checked property. See below:

```
if (document.getElementById('genderFemale').checked)
{
  alert("The Ideal weight for you(women) is : " +women);
} 
  else if (document.getElementById('genderMale').checked)
{ 
  alert("The Ideal weight for you (men) is : " +men);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Height:<input style="margin-left: 30px; padding: 0; width: 102px" list="units" type="number" step="any"  name="Height" id="height">
<div id="myForm">
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderMale" value="male" checked style="margin-left: 20px; padding: 0;"> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderFemale" value="female"> Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</div>

<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

and js:

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(){

var men = 22*Math.pow(document.getElementById('height').value,2);
var women = 22*Math.pow(document.getElementById('height').value - 0.1,2);
var rates = document.getElementById('myForm').value;

    if (document.getElementById('genderFemale').checked) 
    {
      alert("The Ideal weight for you(women) is : " +women);
    } 
      else if (document.getElementById('genderMale').checked)
    { 
      alert("The Ideal weight for you (men) is : " +men);
    }
 }
```

made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4932u5j/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need <IE8 compatibility, you might consider switching to document.querySelector, like this:

```
var value = document.querySelector('[name=gender]:checked').value;
if (value === "female") {
  alert("The Ideal weight for you(women) is : " +women);
} else if (value == "male") { 
  alert("The Ideal weight for you (men) is : " +men);
}
```